# How to slice out column names based on column into row of new dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a df that looks like this

```
data.answers.1542213647002.subItemType   data.answers.1542213647002.value.1542213647003               
     thank you for the response                   TRUE
```

How do I slice out the column name only for columns that have the string `.value.` and the column has the value `TRUE` into a new df like so?:

new_df

```
old_column_names
data.answers.1542213647002.value.1542213647003
```

I have roughly 100 more columns with `.value.` in it but not all of them have TRUE in them as values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assume this sample df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[1,2]*5,
                   'col2.value.something':[True,False]*5,
                   'col3.value.something':[5]*10,
                   'col4':[True]*10})
```

then

```
# boolean indexing with stack
new = pd.DataFrame(list(df[((df==True) & (df.columns.str.contains('.value.')))].stack().index))

# drop duplicates
new = new.drop(columns=0).drop_duplicates()

    1
0   col2.value.something
```

Comment: Thank you for the response: I get error `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1` when I run your line. I did it this way:

    `new_df['new_col'] = pd.DataFrame(list(df[((df==True) & (df.columns.str.contains('.value.')))].stack().index))`

Comment: @RustyShackleford You are getting that error because you are trying to pass a dataframe with two columns and set it to one column in another dataframe

Comment: @RustyShackleford sure but I need some more information: is `new_df` already a dataframe or do you want that to be the variable name?

Comment: it is not a new df. However with your solution I recreated the dataframe with your logic and added the new rows. I dont think we need to rework the solution. Thank you so much